# I want to assign a string variable inside python raw_input

Tags: python, python-2.7

---reality---

```
a = "email@gmail.com"

b = raw_input()
> a            # enter
```

result : a

---desired answer---

```
a = "email@gmail.com"

b = raw_input()
> a            # enter
```

result : "email@gmail.com"

When I use it as input, it works normally, but when I use raw_input, why do I get such a result? And what's the solution?

Thank you.

Comment: That's precisely what `raw_input` does *not* do. It explicitly simply gives you the *raw input*, without further interpretation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a toy problem, just use `input()`. This is the equivalent of `eval(raw_input())`. Don't do this if there is even the possibility that you do not trust input. Whoever has control of the input can execute arbitrary code in your program. So it's a major security vulnerability.

For a more secure approach, put all the values you want to be accessible in a dictionary, and then key that dictionary by your input. The reason to do it this way is that user can only select from the predefined keys you have given them.

eg.

```py
values = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
key = raw_input()
result = values[key]
print(result)
```

A halfway house might be to use `globals()` or `locals()`. `globals()` returns your module's global dictionary and `locals()` collects all the local variables into a dictionary for you. This will allow the user to select any name from either of those sets of names. So they might be able to select values you want to keep secret.

eg.

```py
password = 'foo'
a = 1
b = 2
key = raw_input() # password would be a valid input here
result = vars()[key]
print(result) # so here we would leak the value of password
```

As a side note, you are using Python 2. Python 2 is long past its end of life and no longer receives security updates. All new projects should ideally use one of the more recent versions of Python 3 (eg. 3.10). Python 3 only has `input()`, but its behaviour is that of `raw_input()` in Python 2.

Answer (score 2):

If you give input, it is considered as string.

You can use dictionary to save your e-mail and then use input string as key to get value (Python3 code):

```
your_dict = {'a': 'email@gmail.com'}
b = input()
print(your_dict[b])
#email@gmail.com
```

Comment: Op is using python 2. This code is for python 3 and will do something different on python 2. Effectively, `input()` on python 2 calls `eval()` on the string before returning it.

Comment: You are right. :)

Answer (score 0):

What you receive through the input() function will be a  string.so you just asking to print that string.
you can read more about `globals()` dynamically assign variables from here.
[How can you dynamically create variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables)

you can use `globals()` function like this.
(Using `input()` for Python 3.)

```
a = "email@gmail.com"

print(globals()[input()])
```

a

email@gmail.com